# Excel VBA: MoviesByGenre Function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write an Excel VBA function that will do two things. First, it will determine the number of movies in each genre and print it to the immediate window using the printMovieData function I have written. Secondly, it will return the genre that has the most number of movies using the FindMax function I have written. I have provided my codes for printMovieData, FindMax, and what I have so far for MoviesByGenre, however, I am not sure what I am doing wrong and am looking for help to get the function working. Currently, Excel is returning the `#VALUE!` error.

printMovieData:

```
Function printMovieData(title As String, arrayTopic, arrayOther)

printMovieData = ""

For i = 1 To UBound(arrayTopic)
    Debug.Print arrayTopic(i) & " : " & arrayOther(i)
Next i

End Function
```

FindMax:

```
Function FindMax(valueArray, nameArray) As String

Dim i As Integer
Dim maxValue As Variant

maxValue = 0

For i = 1 To UBound(valueArray)
    If valueArray(i) >= maxValue Then
        maxValue = valueArray(i)
        FindMax = nameArray(i)
    End If
Next i

End Function
```

MoviesByGenre:

```
Function MoviesByGenre(genreRng As Range) As String

Dim i As Integer
Dim genreArray(1 To 4) As String
Dim countArray

genreArray(1) = Action
genreArray(2) = Comedy
genreArray(3) = Drama
genreArray(4) = Musical

For i = 1 To UBound(genreArray)
    For j = 1 To genreRng.Count
        If genreRng.Cells(j) = genreArray(i) Then
            countArray(i) = countArray(i) + 1
        End If
    Next j
Next i

MoviesByGenre = printMovieData("Movies by Genre", genreArray, countArray)

MoviesByGenre = FindMax(countArray, genreArray)

End Function
```

Comment: `genreArray(1) = Action` should be `genreArray(1) = "Action"` - same for the other items in `genreArray`. Also Google for ***Why should I use Option Explicit in VBA?***.

Comment: I have now updated all the elements of genreArray elements, I am still getting the same error. Do you notice anything else wrong? I still can't seem to figure it out

Comment: What is the content of genreRng?

Comment: Remember to state whether you are passing parameters by ByRef or ByVal

Comment: Can we see some of your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TBH there are quite a lot of reasons why I wouldn't expect your code to work.
There are some assumptions made such as how you use `genreRng.Count`. This is assuming data to count is either one row or one column.

The following assumes that `genreRng.Cells.Count`, `Ubound(genreArray)` and `UBound(countArray)` are all the same. You don't ensure this.

There are missing variable declarations, no use of `Option Explicit` and a number of other things.

Overarching though, is that I think you want a different object to handle your count. This is where `Collection` and `Scripting Dictionaries` are very useful.

You can have the key as the genre and the count is held in the associated value. If the key already exists, i.e. a repeat genre, just add one to the existing count.

With that in mind, a starting point, might be something like (sorry, no error handling added):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Dim genreCount As Object

    Set genreCount = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set genreCount = MoviesByGenre(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A3"), genreCount)

    printMovieData "Movies by genre", genreCount

    FindMax genreCount

End Sub
Public Function MoviesByGenre(ByRef genreRng As Range, ByVal genreCount As Object) As Object

    Dim j As Long

    For j = 1 To genreRng.Count 'assumes  1 column/row

        Dim currentGenre As String
        currentGenre = genreRng.Cells(j, 1)

        If Not genreCount.Exists(currentGenre) Then
            genreCount.Add currentGenre, 1
        Else
            genreCount(currentGenre) = genreCount(currentGenre) + 1
        End If

    Next j

    Set MoviesByGenre = genreCount

End Function
Public Function printMovieData(ByVal title As String, ByVal genreCount As Object)

Dim key As Variant

Debug.Print title & vbCrLf 'put to next line

For Each key In genreCount.keys

    Debug.Print key & " : " & genreCount(key)

Next key

End Function

Public Function FindMax(ByVal genreCount As Object) As String

    Dim maxValue As Long
    Dim maxGenre As String
    Dim key As Variant

    For Each key In genreCount.keys

        If genreCount(key) > maxValue Then
            maxValue = genreCount(key)
            maxGenre = key
        End If

    Next key

    Debug.Print vbNewLine & "Max genre is " & maxGenre & " with " & maxValue

End Function
```

Input and output:

Input:

[image: Input]

Output:

[image: Output]